# Console.info is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Console.log is doesn't show any information. Does any one have idea what is wrong with FF.

```
console.info( "test" );
```

Comment: Do you have the logging level set lower than "info"? Is this the built-in console of FireBug?

Comment: what is logging level ?

Comment: See: http://i.imgur.com/NrFzVd9.png

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Add this as an answer ;) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the logging level set lower than "info"? Is this the built-in console of FireBug?

[image]